# I add checkbox on my DGV, and i want to add it from another form. C#

Tags: c#

I selected value using checkbox on my DGV, I want to add the selected value to my another form which will display on the datagrid view.

Comment: You have to give better explanation like Which form is parent one? How each form is opened? , etc.

Comment: its like when want to add that value and it will be your choice.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the forms?

Answer (score 0):

Access to a DGV cell:

```
bool b = (bool)dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value;
```